# jQuery toastr.js limit the number of message displayed at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, toastr

I am using jQuery **toastr.js** js to show notifications and now i received new requirement to display only 5 notifications at a time.

So how i can extend **toastr.js** to fulfil my needs, as i have checked there is another version of **toastr.js** using angular and it has this option to limit the number of displayed toast at once `maxOpened`, i want same functionality in jQuery tostr.js

i know there is a event which fires when showing/hiding toast.

```
toastr.subscribe(function(args){
 console.log(args);
});
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks